# Swing Components

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set my GUI as mentioned :
Having a transperent JPanel appearing above a Canvas. (using JLayeredPane)
I read a alot about this topic on web, and realized the problem meshing up heavyweight components (Canvas)
and lightweight components (JPanel), I Have tried to solve this in many ways but none works.
(using Java jdk1.6.0_45)

Is there a way to get my GUI as desired ?

sample code :

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            myWindow frame = new myWindow();
            frame.setSize(950, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static class myWindow extends JFrame {

        private Canvas redCanvas;
        private JPanel upperPanel;
        private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

        public myWindow() {
            init();
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
            getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
            layeredPane.add(redCanvas,2);
            layeredPane.add(upperPanel, 0);
        }

        private void init() {
            layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            layeredPane.setLayout(null);

            upperPanel = new JPanel();
            JButton jButton = new JButton("Check");
            jButton.setSize(50, 50);
            jButton.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
            upperPanel.add(jButton);
            upperPanel.setLocation(70, 5);
            upperPanel.setOpaque(false);
            upperPanel.setSize(400, 200);
            upperPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,15));

            redCanvas = new Canvas();
            redCanvas.setBackground(Color.RED);
            redCanvas.setSize(500, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having specifically?

Comment: And why are you using a Canvas?

Comment: The problem is it doesnt works. when i move the transperent panel above the canvas, the intersected area shows the layer below the canvas, canvas is my only option because im using an external jar that can draw only on canvas component.

Answer (score 1):

> "Im trying to set my GUI as mentioned : Having a transperent JPanel appearing above a Canvas."

1. You were right in your speculation not use `Canvas` I switched the `Canvas` to `JPanel`

   ```
   JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
   ```
2. You need to be using an `Integer` and not a primitive `int` initializing the layer. See in documentation

   > When adding a component to a layered pane you specify the layer with an Integer. When using setLayer to change a component's layer, you use an int. You might think that if you use an int instead of an Integer with the add method, the compiler would complain or your program would throw an illegal argument exception. But the compiler says nothing, which results in a common layered pane problem.

   ```
   layeredPane.add(redCanvas, new Integer(0));
   layeredPane.add(upperPanel, new Integer(1));
   ```

### Side Notes

- I know that you need to set the bounds and sizes for components in a `JLayeredPane`, *and* this was probably just practice, but just so you know, you should not be setting the size to all your components. Instead use LayoutManagers so your GUI is more fluid and not rigid. See more one [**Laying out Components Withing a Containter**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn more about how to use layout.
- Instead of setting the size to the frame, you should call `pack()`, and all the preferred sizes will we respected.
- Run your Swing programs from the [**Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) like below. Also see [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
              myWindow frame = new myWindow();
              ....
          }
      });
  }
  ```

---

Alas, here is your program *with* the above two fixes, but *without* the side-notes. You can figure them out with the links I gave you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myWindow frame = new myWindow();
        frame.setSize(950, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    static class myWindow extends JFrame {

        private JPanel redCanvas;
        private JPanel upperPanel;
        private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

        public myWindow() {
            init();
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
            layeredPane.add(redCanvas, new Integer(0));
            layeredPane.add(upperPanel, new Integer(1));
            getContentPane().add(layeredPane);

        }

        private void init() {
            layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            layeredPane.setLayout(null);

            upperPanel = new JPanel();
            JButton jButton = new JButton("Check");
            jButton.setSize(50, 50);
            jButton.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
            upperPanel.add(jButton);
            upperPanel.setLocation(70, 5);
            upperPanel.setOpaque(false);
            upperPanel.setSize(400, 200);
            upperPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 15));

            redCanvas = new JPanel();
            redCanvas.setBackground(Color.RED);
            redCanvas.setOpaque(true);

            redCanvas.setSize(500, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I get what your saying, but in my case the only choice is using canvas (The only component that fits the requirements).